# How do I make AppCode find the path to Xcode Version 4.3 (4E109)?

Tags: xcode4, appcode

I just installed Xcode Version 4.3 (4E109). I am a JetBrains Appcode user and Appcode now nolonger can find Xcode which now installs by default in /Applications.

I tried running: `sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications` but that had no effect.

What's my move here?

Thanks,
Doug

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Got it. I used the wrong path:

Correct path: `sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer`

Comment: Tried this but i still get the Xcode not found in '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer' error :(